# Is there a javascript function that takes a string as input and parse that string asif it is HTML and return me the according element?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a javascript function that takes a string as input and parse that string asif it is HTML and return me the according element?

example: `F("<div id='outer'><div id='inner'><span hello></span></div></div>")`
will return me a div HTMLElement that have a child div which in turn has a span child.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? This framework can do what you want. Use $("<div id='outer'><div id='inner'><span hello></span></div></div>")

Comment: no jqueries please. i want a javascript solution

Comment: See my post below. What do you think about this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what about `DOMParser`?
Here is an example:

```
var str = '<div id="outer"><div id="inner"><span> hello</span></div></div>';

function parseStringToDOMElement (str)
{
    var xmlDoc = null;
    if (window.DOMParser)
    {
        var parser = new DOMParser ();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString (str, "text/xml");
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject ("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = false;
        xmlDoc.loadXML (str);
    }
    return xmlDoc.firstChild;

}

var node=parseStringToDOMElement(str);
console.log(node);
```

I hope it will be helpfull

Answer (score 5):

No there is no such function. But you can use jQuery `$("<div id='outer'><div id='inner'><span hello></span></div></div>")` which will do what you want.

Comment: So in fact there is such a function: the jQuery element!

Comment: To be precise, to get the actual HTLMElement, you'd need `.get(0)`.

Comment: i want a javascript solution. what is the implementation of jQuery? did they really parse that string and create the dom by hand? seems impossible

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple plain javascript solution :

http://jsfiddle.net/7HdJc/1/

```
function returnTheNodes(htmlStr)
{
var myCont = document.createElement('DIV'); // create a div element
myCont.innerHTML = htmlStr; // create its children with the string 
return myCont.childNodes;  // return the children elements created :)

}


var newElems = returnTheNodes("<div id='outer'><div id='inner'><span hello></span></div></div>");


for(var i = 0; i < newElems.length ; i++ )
{
 alert(newElems[i].id); // newElems[0] has the first DIV

}
```

Comment: +1: I was about to post an answer about `innerHTML`, but my answer didn't have it all neatly wrapped up in a function complete with jsfiddle.